# Convert char[] to String in BTrace

Tags: java, debugging, trace, instrumentation, btrace

I'm profiling application with [btrace](https://btrace.dev.java.net) and faced with limitation. I try to get a name of current `java.lang.Thread`. Normaly you can call `getName()` but it's forbidden in btrace-scripts (any calls exception `BTraceUtils`).
Is there any idea how to get String from `char[]`?

The original task is check if name of thread contains sub-string and only then log out tracing info (reducing output).

Comment: I don't know btrace, but is it possible to simply use `new String(charArray)` in your case?

Comment: like chris_l I don't know btrace but could you create a string variable, iterate through the char[] and add each char to the string

Comment: that's a problem - no new object creation is alowed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just use the "built-in" function ***name(thread)*** from **BTraceUtils**. One of the types it takes as its argument is Thread and it returns the thread's name. Also, there is ***threadId(thread)*** function which returns the thread's ID.

You can find many useful function in the **BTraceUtils** class - check out the online [javadoc](http://btrace.kenai.com/javadoc/1.1/com/sun/btrace/BTraceUtils.html).

Cheers,

JB

Answer (score 3):

Some info that may be helpful to others:

https://btrace.dev.java.net/source/browse/btrace/docs/usersguide.html?rev=1.7

> In particular, a BTrace class
>
> - can not create new objects.
> - can not create new arrays.
> - can not throw exceptions.
> - can not catch exceptions.
> - can not make arbitrary instance or static method calls - only the public
>     static methods of
>     com.sun.btrace.BTraceUtils class may
>     be called from a BTrace program.
> - can not assign to static or instance fields of target program's classes and
>     objects. But, BTrace class can assign
>     to it's own static fields ("trace
>     state" can be mutated).
> - can not have instance fields and methods. Only static public void
>     returning methods are allowed for a
>     BTrace class. And all fields have to
>     be static.
> - can not have outer, inner, nested or local classes.
> - can not have synchronized blocks or synchronized methods.
> - can not have loops (for, while, do..while)
> - can not extend arbitrary class (super class has to be
>     java.lang.Object)
> - can not implement interfaces.
> - can not contains assert statements.
> - can not use class literals.

http://btrace.kenai.com/javadoc/1.1/com/sun/btrace/BTraceUtils.html